# Does the test class create implementations to inject in spring dependency injection

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

In this example on spring dependency injection [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/SpringDependencyInjection/article.html)

Whne the final test class is run, after this line:

```
MySpringBeanWithDependency test = (MySpringBeanWithDependency) factory
        .getBean("mySpringBeanWithDependency");
```

Which implementation of writer class will get injected? The test class still is responsbile for creating an actual implementation and injecting it before calling business methods on the Writer. Is it true?

Answer (score 0):

In both the annotation-based example and the XML-based example, Spring will inject the `NiceWriter` bean into the `MySpringBeanWithDependency` bean.

For the annotation example, this is because the `NiceWriter` class is annotated with `@Service` (while the `Writer` class is not) and Spring will discover this via classpath scanning and autowire it into `MySpringBeanWithDependency`.

For the XML example, this is because the `NiceWriter` class is used to define the bean with id `writer`, which is referenced as the "writer" property of the bean with id `mySpringBeanWithDependency`.

In both cases, the `MySpringBeanWithDependency` bean is instantiated with dependencies injected via Spring, and is thus ready to use. It is **not** responsible for managing its `IWriter` dependency. This is why *dependency injection* (DI for short) usually goes hand-in-hand with *inversion-of-control* (IoC for short). Spring provides an IoC container that uses DI.